# How to check multiple dropdowns has got value or not using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to check if all those fields have got value or not if not then show an alert.
[image]

i have tried this :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var session = $('#getsessionid').val();
            var class_level = $('#getprogramLevelid').val();
            var class_student = $('#getprogramid').val();
            var medium = $('#getmediumid').val();
            var group = $('#getgroupid').val();
            var shift = $('#getshiftid').val();
            var section = $('#getsectionid').val();
            if((session && class_level && class_student && medium && group && shift && section) ==""){
                alert("Please Insert Values");
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Only image to describe your question is not good practice . Please show your effort what you try include code .......... .

Comment: posted all those codes

Comment: @TanaySyed You can use jQuery `$.each` to iterate through all your inputs. Also - try not to use `alert()`, style your inputs or create custom notifications instead.

Answer (score 0):

A small demo to help you out. Hope this helps:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $('option[value!="0"]:selected');
  if (selected.length == $('select').length) {
    console.log('All dropdowns have been selected.');
  } else {
    console.log('Some dropdowns have not yet selected.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggler_container">
  <select name="select" id="aaa">
        <option value="0">---</option>
        <option value="1">AAA</option>
        <option value="2">BBB</option>
    </select>
  <select name="select" id="bbb">
        <option value="0">---</option>
        <option value="1">AAA</option>
        <option value="2">BBB</option>
    </select>
  <select name="select" id="ccc">
        <option value="0">---</option>
        <option value="1">AAA</option>
        <option value="2">BBB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```